# How can i start a rails application on a tcserver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have tried to run rails on mongrel, so i included gem 'mongrel' in the gemfile and started `rails server mongrel`, the server started fine. But i need to start rails on 'tcserver'. How can i do that?. `rails server tcserver` throws `LoadError: no such file to load -- rack/handler/tcserver` which is quite obvious. Please let me know how to start a rails application on a tcserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vfabric TC Server is an adaption of Apache Tomcat, and as such is a Java servlet container. It does not run Ruby-on-Rails as is.

You would need to use JRuby, and a tool such as [Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler/), which packages Rails apps into  WARs compatible with Tomcat.

[This](http://techylinguist.com/posts/2012/01/13/deploy-jruby-rails-application-war/) Is a good step-by-step for the process. (Replace Tomcat with TC server instance)

Comment: Thank you, i'm using jruby anyway. I will install warbler. I did not find any detailed documentation on net. Do you know any website which has the detailed documentation of starting rails with jruby on tc server?